# Why does lightdm-gtk-greeter not depend on lightdm?

Tags: lightdm

I had assumed that I would also get lightdm installed when I installed the package lightdm-gtk-greeter, but that was not the case. Looking up the package [info](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lightdm-gtk-greeter) it was clear that there was no dependency declared between the greeter and lightdm. Is it possible to use a lightdm greeter without lightdm?

Answer (score 0):

`lightdm-gtk-greeter` depends on `liblightdm-gobject-1-0` that contains the interface to LightDM that the greeter is using.

`liblightdm-gobject-1-0` depends on `lightdm`  so `lightdm-gtk-greeter` indirectly depends on `lightdm`, too

Comment: This is incorrect. [`liblightdm-gobject-1-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liblightdm-gobject-1-0) only recommends lightdm.

Comment: My above comment is also incorrect, liblightdm-gobject-1-0 only suggests lightdm.